# sharepoint online List Items not appearing in the search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

we created a custom list in sharepoint online site by exporting excel data to sharepoint custom list after which the list items are not displaying in the search results

we even tried to reindex the custom list but even after which the search results are not showing the list items

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. Do you have search enabled on your list? (See more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-to-be-searchable-d7ba92db-8618-43fe-87ee-adf03d973062).)
2. Do you have search enabled on the site housing your list? (See more [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-to-be-searchable-d7ba92db-8618-43fe-87ee-adf03d973062).)
3. Does the user have permissions to view the data?
4. Sometimes [the O365 crawls take longer than expected](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/10/waiting-for-search-crawl-in-office-365.html).

Comment: I have all of this enabled and still items from my lists don't appear in searches. And the content has been in there for months.